# Get the selected value using from dropdownlist using @Html.DropDownList

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Here is the code below. the selected value senda to the controller.

```
@Html.DropDownList("pagesize", new List<SelectListItem>
{
    new SelectListItem() {Text = "10", Value="10"},
    new SelectListItem() {Text = "20", Value="20"},
    new SelectListItem() {Text = "30", Value="30"},
    new SelectListItem() {Text = "40", Value="40"}
}, new { onChange = string.Format("location.href = '{0}'", @Url.Action("Logs", "Logging")) })
```

Controller:-

```
public ActionResult Logs(int pagesize=10)
{
}
```

Comment: Yo code does not pass the selected value to the controller. You need modify the url to add the selected value

Comment: that is what i want the select value i am not getting it from the from the given dropdownlist, what is the procedure to add the selected value to the url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `onChange` attribute and use [unobtrusive javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript). The function needs to add the selected value to the url as a route parameter.

```
var url = '@Url.Action("Logs", "Logging")';
$('#pagesize').change(function() {
  location.href = url + '?pagesize=' + $(this).val();
}
```

Side note: You should be generating the SelectList in the controller, but in any case in can be simplified to

```
@Html.DropDownList("pagesize", new SelectList(new List<int>(){ 10, 20, 30, 40 }))
```